# Laravel customize CronJob for timing scheduling at 15 days and x days

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created an Application. in this application I have to set cron-Job schedular suppose user account has been created but doesn't login for 15 Days or more than 15 Days then he/she should get an Reminder Email. How can I customize this Cron-Job schedular once user account created? Thanks In advance.

Comment: so You need to check that if the account is created and he has not been logged in for past fifteen days you need to send the remainder email

Comment: I know i have set mailer as well but only mail should be trigger after 15 days if user doesn't logged in so how to customize schedular at kernel

Comment: do you have any column for `last_logged_in` in the users table or some other table

Comment: Yes Logs table also created to store last_logged_in to every user

Comment: table name and filed name please

Comment: This is what you are looking for https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

Comment: Table Name - users and fields are -user_id, user_number, salutation, first_name, last_name, email, password, photo, mobile, created_at, updated_at, last_login_at, api_token,status_line. Yes i went through that doc but doesn't have customize solution

Comment: Do you need to send email exactly at 24x15 hours? If not, just do a daily cron job to check if last_logged_in is more than 15 days from today using mysql datediff, and send bulk email to selected users.

Comment: Great I'll Try this solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remind users who have not been logged in since 15 days ago and also send email once every 15 days try this:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function(){
        $users=User::where('last_logged_in',"<",Carbon::now()->subDays(15))
            ->get();
        //TODO:: Send email to users implementation
    })->cron('0 0 */15 * *');
}
```